# Covariance of random sums

Tags: probability, covariance, bilinear-operator

How can I compute
$$cov(\sum^N a_k,\sum^{N'}a_k)$$
where $N$, $N'$ are **random dependent variables** and $a_k$ iid random variables , as a function of cov(N,N'), $var(N)$, $var(N')$, $var(a_k)$ and all of their expectation value ?

$N$ and  $N'$ are bounded and positive.

My best shot :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    cov(X,Y)&=cov(\sum^Na_k,\sum^{N'}a_k)\\
    &=cov(\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N'}a_k)\\
    &=cov(\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N'}a_k)\\
    &=\sum\sum cov(\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\mathbb{1}_{k'<N'}a_{k'})\\
    &=\sum\sum \mathbb{1}_{k<N\cap k'<N'}cov(a_k,a_{k'})\\
    &=\sum \mathbb{1}_{k<\min(N,N')}var(a_k)\\
    &=\min(N,N')var(a)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Feels wrong, is the 4th step right ? I use bilinearity on infinite sums..

Thank you

Comment: You could perhaps write $\sum_k^\infty {\mathbf 1}_{k\le X} A_k$.